# How to avoid refetching data in React-native

Tags: react-native

I am using [react-native-navigation-drawer](https://github.com/ilansas/react-native-navigation-drawer). I fetch data from url (inside componentDidMount) to render first page. Then I go to second/third (other) pages. When I reselect/choose First Page again. It refetch data from url. How I can keep that data so that I can avoid fetching url again and again until user click on refresh button. Any help, please. I tried fetching data in parent view and passProps but if I do so, I can't refresh data.

```
getInitialState: function() {
return {
      dataSource: null,
      loaded: false,
      networkError : false,
  };
},

componentDidMount: function() {
if(this.props.firstTime){//This is used to fetch data only the in first time. 
  this.fetchData(); //call function to fetch data from url
}
console.log("Issue View First Time :: " + this.props.firstTime);
},

fetchData: function() {

fetch(REQUEST_URL)
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((responseData) => {
    this.setState({
      dataSource: responseData,  //Want to keep this information to render again.
      loaded: true,
    });
  })
   .catch((error) => {
    console.warn('error ::: ' + error);

    this.setState({
      networkError: true, //used to render error View 
    });
  })
  .done(()=> {
  });
},
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a dump question. I figured it out. 
I declare a variable and set state of dataSource with that variable.

```
var KEEPED_DATA = [];

var FirstView = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
     dataSource: KEEPED_DATA,
     networkError : false,
    };
  },

  componentWillMount: function() {
    if(!KEEPED_DATA.length){
      this.fetchData();
    }
  },

 fetchData: function() { 
    //Fetching data from url
    KEEPED_DATA = responseData; 
 },

 render: function() {
    //render
```

});